# Argv doesnt work with char pointer on terminal

Tags: c, initialization, undefined-behavior, c-strings, argv

I want to write a program that when I am on terminal and write `prog.exe -u word` will transform `word` to uppercase otherwise skip the process. but when I compile the code below, I get nothing on screen and I couldn't figure out why the error occurs.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

char u[] = "-u";

void upper(const char *src, char *dest);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Input at least 3 argument!\n");
    } else
    if (!(strcmp(argv[1], u))) {
        char *output;
        upper(argv[2], output);
        printf("%s\n", output);
    } else {
        printf("No option\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

void upper(const char *src, char *dest) {
    while (*src) {
        if (*src >= 97 && *src <= 122) {
            *dest = *src - 32;
        } else {
            *dest = *src;
        }
        src++;
        dest++;
    }
    *dest = *src;
}
```

Comment: `char * output; upper(argv[2],output);` What do you think is happening here?

Comment: never use magic numbers like 97 or 122. Use `*src >= 'a' && *src <= 'z'` instead

Answer (score 1):

The pointer `output` declared like

```
char * output;
```

is uninitialized and has an indeterminate value.

So using it in the function `upper` invokes undefined behavior.

Instead of the pointer you should use a character array large enough to store the passed string to the function.

If the compiler supports variable length arrays then you can write

```
char output[ strlen( argv[2] ) + 1 ];
```

And this if statement

```
else if( strcmp(argv[1],u) == 0 ){
```

will be more readable than this if statement

```
else if(!(strcmp(argv[1],u))){
```

Within the function it will be at least better to use character symbols `'a'` and `'z'` instead of the magic numbers `97` and `122` in the if statement

```
if(*src >= 97 && *src <= 122){
  *dest = *src - 32;
}
```

Though it is even better to use standard function `islower` and `toupper` declared in the header `<ctype.h>`.

The function can be declared and defined the following way

```
#include <ctype.h>

//...

char * upper( char *dest, const char *src )
{
    char *result = dest;

    do
    {
        if ( islower( ( unsigned char )*src ) )
        {
            *dest++ = toupper( ( unsigned char )*src );
        }
        else
        {
            *dest++ = *src;
        }
    } while ( *src++ );

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void upper(const char *src, char *dest) {
  char *tmp = dest; // hold pointer
  while(*src) {
    *dest = (*src >= 97 && *src <= 122) ? *src - 32 : src;
    ++src; ++dest;
  }
  *dest = '\0'; // end of string
  dest = tmp;
}
```

Comment: What does that change?

Comment: You need to back a pointer of your `dest` variable that points at the address where your `dest` starts. What is happening in your case is that you return the address where `dest` variable ends, therefore you loose your actual data

Comment: @yemo The function deals with its local variables. So original pointers passed to the function are not being changed.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yes you are right, my fault. I didn't consider the address of 'outside' variable and local manipulations with that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The program has undefined behavior because you attempt to store the converted string to an uninitialized pointer `output`.

Note that using hard coded constants such as `97`, `122` and `32` is both confusing and non portable to non-ASCII environments. You should use the macros and functions from `<ctype.h>` for readability and portability.

You could simply modify the argument string in place this way:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void upper(char *str);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Input at least 3 arguments!\n");
    } else
    if (!(strcmp(argv[1], "-u"))) {
        printf("%s\n", upper(argv[2]));
    } else {
        printf("No option\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

char *upper(char *str) {
    for (char *p = str; *p; p++) {
        *p = toupper((unsigned char)*p);
    }
    return str;
}
```